# Does this Formula have a Name?

Tags: probability

Does this formula (or a piece of it) have a name?

$$P = W \times \left[1 - (1-x_1)(1-x_2) \ldots (1-x_n) \right]$$

where 
$x_i$ are scores between 0 and 1.
$W$ is a weight (so not really relevant I suppose).

It is used in an application to combine weighted scores. The documentation doesn't define it beyond writing it out. I'm curious if it's a standard calculation.

Comment: It looks a bit like a probability calculation, but if it is, it wouldn't have a standard name of which I am aware.

Comment: Please state what the $x_i,P $ are. Please give reference to the textbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) in disguise.

\begin{align}
1 - &(1-x_1)(1-x_2) \cdots (1-x_n)  \\
{}={} &1-1  \\
  &+ [x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_2]  \\
  &- [x_1(x_2 + \cdots + x_n) + x_2(x_3 + \cdots x_n) + \cdots x_{n-1}x_n]  \\
  &+ [\text{sum of products of distinct $x_i$, taken three at a time}] \\
  &- [\text{sum of products of distinct $x_i$, taken four at a time}] \\
  &\vdots  \\
  &\pm x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n
\end{align}